# Acces denied IE : form.submit() file upload jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, file, plugins, upload

I'm using blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload and I'm getting and error of "access denied" on internet explorer (all versions). In fact it is a jQuery error, jquery.js, line 3241 character 6 development library. The flow is like this: click on a button, fireing input file button, listening for onchange event and beginning upload. 
Then I get this error and I don't know from where it is comming.

Please help me out with this.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem with this same plugin, and the cause was with this: I was using JavaScript to trigger a click on the file input, rather than relying on a click on the File Input itself. Problem is, IE doesn't like this. It won't let you submit a form with JavaScript that has a file input field containing data added via JavaScript.

There's no way around this - except allowing them to click on the file input field directly, rather than triggering with JavaScript. The reason I was triggering the click was for style reason. I wanted to use a link rather than the actual file field, but with some fancy CSS I was still able to achieve the same look.

http://pastebin.com/qcYPUR6p

Comment: Is there a short snippet you could add that demonstrates your answer? You can [edit] it in and use the code format button!